# Custom tabs design with Swipeable Views

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-tabs

I've followed a tutorial on how to create tabs that you can swipe between using fragments, but now as I'm done with the tutorial I need to implement a custom design on the tabs. Can I do that because that is not explained in the tutorial.

*This is the [tutorial I followed](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

Answer (score 0):

Create custom tab’s layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabsLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip" android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tabsText" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="15dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Customize the look and feel of the view

tabs_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabsLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector"
    android:padding="10dip" android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tabsText" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="15dip" android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_selector" />
</LinearLayout>
```

similarly set text and background selector.use it as your new layout

you can reference [this](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

create xml(tab1) in drawble folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- When selected, use grey -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/videos_gray"
  android:state_selected="true" />
<!-- When not selected, use white-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/videos_white" />
```

and use that in java file

```
// Create an actionbar
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

// Hide Actionbar Icon
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

// Hide Actionbar Title
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

// Create Actionbar Tabs
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

// Create first Tab
tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(new FragmentTab1());
// Create your own custom icon
tab.setIcon(R.drawable.tab1);
actionBar.addTab(tab);

// Create Second Tab
tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(new FragmentTab2());
// Set Tab Title
tab.setText("Tab2");
actionBar.addTab(tab);

// Create Third Tab
tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(new FragmentTab3());
// Set Tab Title
tab.setText("Tab3");
actionBar.addTab(tab);
```